# Heroku convert .mdb to csv or how to use multiple buildpacks together

Tags: python, ms-access, heroku

Have a simple python application deployed on heroku and I need to manage with microsoft access database (.mdb). I read, that I have to use mdb-tools for this purposes.
Example - converting mdb database to csv:

bash:  `mdb-export 'mdb-file' 'table-name' > result.csv`
(I am going to run it as subprocess in python)

I installed https://github.com/iblogbox/heroku-buildpack-mdbtools build pack.
But when I try test it:

```
heroku run bash
mdb-export
```

I get `bash: mdb-export: command not found`

Questions:

- Can I use multiple buildpacks in heroku?
- Is it possible to convert .mdb file to csv or excel file in linux?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer:

You don't need heroku-buildpack-mdbtools to use several buildpacks in your heroku application.

Following this arcticle (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)
You can use following

bash: `heroku buildpacks:set your-first-buildpack`

then

bash: `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 your-additional-buildpack`

I used heroku/python + **https://github.com/profit-strategies/heroku-buildpack-mdbtools** to convert .mdb database (WHO STILL USES MICROSOFT ACCESS IN 2016???) to csv in linux by this command:`mdb-export 'mdb-file' 'table-name' > result.csv`
Just runned this command as a subprocess in python

```
subprocess.call("mdb-export '%s' 'colorado well completions' > Temporary/result.csv" % path_to_mdb, shell=True)
```